# Find .class in parent <li> by JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<!--HTML-->
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>
        <a class="handle-link" href=""><img src=""/>Dashboard</a>
    </li>

    <li class="active">
        <a href="#" class="expand"><img src=""/>Multiple</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="current">
                <a class="handle-link sub-menu" href="">One</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="handle-link sub-menu" href="">Two</a>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <a class="handle-link sub-menu" href="">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a class="handle-link" href=""><img src=""/>Single</a>
    </li>
</ul>


    $('a.handle-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var currentMenuItem = $(this);
        var parentLI = $(currentMenuItem).closest('li');

        if ($(currentMenuItem).hasClass('sub-menu')) {
            if ($(parentLI.hasClass('current'))) {
                alert('This is current');
            }
            else {
                //Error here- 
                alert('This is not current'); //This is not executing
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('this is somewhere else.');
        }
    });
```

When I click on "Two", it also returns "This is current". But it should return "This is not current".

Any help?

Comment: You have to do `var parentLI = $(currentMenuItem).parents('li:first');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(parentLI.hasClass('current'))` is always going to be truthy since jQuery object is returned. You need get rid of the wrapping `$()`

```
if (parentLI.hasClass('current')) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your `if` statement because you are passing a jQuery object(`$(parentLI.hasClass('current'))`) to it which will always be truthy.

So just remove the wrapping `$()` call, so that the value returned by `hasClass` is evaluated by the `if` statement

```
 if (parentLI.hasClass('current')) {
   alert('This is current');
 } else {
   //Error here- 
   alert('This is not current'); //This is not executing
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a.handle-link').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var currentMenuItem = $(this);
  var parentLI = currentMenuItem.parent('li');

  if (currentMenuItem.hasClass('sub-menu')) {
      if (parentLI.hasClass('current')) {
          alert('This is current');
      } else {
          alert('This is not current');
      }
    } else {
        alert('this is somewhere else.');
    }
});
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qw8Lv4qg/3/)

Comment: Maybe because when you first posted your answer it was wrong.